# Where should I put the stylesheet link in the html code?

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:
Whatever modification I make in the CSS file, it doesn't affect my target HTML file.
It previously was named "index.html" (Brackets created a copy somehow - I am new to HTML/CSS) and the modifications happened only on that page.
Where am I supposed to put the stylesheet link in the HTML code? head? body?
Here is the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <Title>Acasa</Title>
  </head>
  <body background=".\images\colaj.jpg">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\acasa\acasa.css">
      <embed src=".\music\fundal gloante.mp3" loop="true" autostart="true"                       hidden="true" > 
      <br/>
      <center>
         <img src=".\images\Presentation1.png"text-align: center; border="10" >
      </center>
    
<br/><br/>
     <center><ul>
       <li><a href="cuvant.html" >Cuvant inainte</a></li>
       <li><a href="\site\preview\neutralitate.html">Anii de neutralitate</a></li>
       <li><a href="galerie.html">Intrarea in razboi</a></li>
    <li><a href="galerie.html">Razboiul</a></li>
    <li><a href="colaj.html">Dambovita in razboi</a></li>
        <li<a href="C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\scoala\istorie\site\preview\T.html">Galerie Video</a></li>
       <li><a href="C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\scoala\istorie\site\preview\T.html">Galerie Foto</a></li>
       <li><a href="C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\scoala\istorie\site\preview\T.html">Bibliografie</a></li>
     </ul>
    </center> 
    <br/><br/><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(200,30,30);
    border: 1px solid #555;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li { margin: auto;font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

What is the problem?
Sorry for the long code.Please tell me what mistake I am making, I am totally new to this.

Comment: You should put it inside the head tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific question, I agree with the other answers.  Include CSS in `<head>...</head>`.

However, depending on your browser your underlying issue may be that you are using backslashes in your paths.  Use forward slashes.  Try referencing the stylesheet as `./acasa/acasa.css` (assuming that the CSS file is in fact located in a subdirectory `acasa` relative to where the html file is located).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Title of the document</title>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="author" content=""/>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href=""/>
<link href="yourcssfile.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!--or you can add directly here css codes  -->
<style type="text/css">
 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(200,30,30);
  border: 1px solid #555;
 } /*bla bla bla ........ this is Comment line*/
</style>

<script src="yourscriptfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--if you want you can put the script files 
before </body> tag for the site to be fast  -->

</head>

<body>
  The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

and you can look this site [for learn about first html and css notes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Always put your CSS inside the head of the page

Answer (score 0):

Inside the head tag like below:

```html
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(200,30,30);
    border: 1px solid #555;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li { margin: auto;font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
  </style>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the `header` section:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH_TO_CSS_HERE">
```

Here's an example of a full header from one of my pages:

```
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a coding problem. Maybe your web browser doesn't always reload the css.`

It happens to me a lot with Opera, usually reloading with `ctrl+f5` do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use internal styling then you can put your css in a `<style></style>` block inside the head. Refer attached code.

I would however suggest you to go through the MDN [How CSS works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/How_CSS_works) page and go through the basics. Also check how css can be imported via Internal stylesheets, External stylesheets & Inline stylesheets.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <Title>Acasa</Title>
    <style>
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: rgb(200, 30, 30);
        border: 1px solid #555;
      }

      li a {
        display: block;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      li {
        margin: auto;
        font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
      }

      li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
      }

      li a.active {
        background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
        color: white;
      }

      li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body background=".\images\colaj.jpg">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\acasa\acasa.css">
    <embed src=".\music\fundal gloante.mp3" loop="true" autostart="true" hidden="true">
    <br>
    <br>
    <center>
      <img src=".\images\Presentation1.png" text-align: center; border="10">
    </center>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <center>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="cuvant.html">Cuvant inainte</a></li>
        <li><a href="\site\preview\neutralitate.html">Anii de neutralitate</a></li>
        <li><a href="galerie.html">Intrarea in razboi</a></li>
        <li><a href="galerie.html">Razboiul</a></li>
        <li><a href="colaj.html">Dambovita in razboi</a></li>
        <li><a href="C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\scoala\istorie\site\preview\T.html">Galerie Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\scoala\istorie\site\preview\T.html">Galerie Foto</a></li>
        <li><a href="C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\scoala\istorie\site\preview\T.html">Bibliografie</a></li>
      </ul>
    </center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using external CSS files, it should be always in  section of the HTML page. Please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp for more information.