# Why should I put a stylesheet link in the <head></head> area of my html code?

Tags: html, css

I have a reason to put a link to my stylesheet someplace other than the <head> section of my html.  Example:

```
<html>
....
<head>
....
</head>
<body>
....
<link rel="stylesheet" ....>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I realize that this is considered "wrong", based on my reading of [Where should I put the stylesheet link in the html code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389666/where-should-i-put-the-stylesheet-link-in-the-html-code) .  However, that same page refers to this:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/How_CSS_works .  After reading how CSS works it appears to me that the <link> to the stylesheet can appear ANYWHERE in the html file since the full html is read, parsed, and then CSS is applied.

So, are the answers in the above stackoverflow page just quoting "best practices" or "the way it was 6 years ago" (that stackoverflow question is 6 years old at the time of this writing) or the way it is documented to work and nothing else is guaranteed? If the latter can you please send me a link to the document that states this?

I'm just trying to separate fact from superstition.  Thank you!

Note: I've tried the above on a few different browsers and they all work the same regardless of where I put the <link> (within reason!)

Comment: The advice has certainly changed over the years, so don't put much store in older advice,

Comment: YOu have to put it in the head because according to W3C and WHATWG it is no longer valid to place it inside the body. It only was valid with the usage of the scope attribute but that have been removed in 2015.

Comment: @tacoshy do you have the W3C reference for that, I can’t find it and according to MDN (less authoritatve I know)  link of type stylesheet is OK in body. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: @AHaworth you can simple use the W3C Vallidator which will red-flag it as an error. (both style tag itself aswell as link). PS: the link apparently is no more red flagged only the style tag.

Comment: I am not certain the validator is 100% accurate @tacoshy as the standard has a link with stylesheet as body_ok https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to how to "clarify my specific problem or provide additional details" as requested by the bot. The answers I've seen so far (from the non-bots!) are quite good and appreciated. I feel this question has been addressed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is seeking an answer that separates fact from fiction.

The fact is that the HTML standards group (now WHATWG) have stated that a link which has rel stylesheet is 'body-ok'.

From [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok)

> Keywords that are body-ok affect whether link elements are allowed in the body. The body-ok keywords are dns-prefetch, modulepreload, pingback, preconnect, prefetch, preload, and stylesheet.

Whether you want to put such links in the body depends on the context in which you are working. Some argue that you should not do this e.g. because it makes it more muddly to separate styling and content.

However, the question here clearly states that there is a need to do this in their context.

So, go ahead.

Answer (score -1):

The biggest reason is that you can load the style sheets early, you avoid flash and un-styled content from a later load making such occur.

The browser can start rendering the page with the applied styles while parsing the rest of the content.

Beyond that no rule, you can do what you want but is it best practice; probably not.

Comment: @Anmolkansal can you elaborate on a browser not allowing a stylesheet inside body because of security. I have not come across this before.

Comment: technical incorrect. It will be cached if it is inside the body as well. But there is a rule according to W3C and WHATWG that placing a style tag inside the body is only valid with the usage of the scope attribute. However, this was deprecated in 2015.

Comment: If, for some reason, you place the <link> tag in the <body> section, the browser may still download and cache the CSS file, but this behavior is less predictable and consistent across different browsers and versions. So technically not, I'll remove that statement as it's less true with some browsers and leave this comment.

Comment: There no inherent security concerns.